# Wolfram mathematica show wrong function graph

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematica

I'm trying to plot this function: $\sqrt[3]{3-x}$ in Mathematica. I have tried various numbers in Y range and X range, but wolfram only shows half of the graph.
Google or desmos.com plot the correct function.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5RrV.png

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Saying that a graph is "wrong" is ... wrong. It is a different interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[Sign[#]Abs[#]^(1/3)&[3-x], {x,-1,7}]
```

Comment: Funny, this works but the command the OP used doesn't work. Why is it?

Comment: @RSerrao Because Wolfram gives a nonreal result for $\sqrt[3]{y}$ when $y < 0$, and representing $e^{\pi i/3}\sqrt[3]{\lvert 3-x\rvert}$ for $x > 3$ in a two-dimensional plot isn't so easy, I think.

Answer (score 1):

For me `Plot[CubeRoot[3 - x], {x, -12, 12}]` is working.

Comment: Funny, this works but the command the OP used doesn't work. Why is it?

Comment: I think that Mathematica considers the expressions of the form $(x)^{1/n}$ only for $x \geq 0$. Otherwise you have to specify $Sqrt$ or $CubeRoot$.